# Is there a CLI to tail logs from AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a CLI utility for tailing logs from Elastic Beanstalk applications.  Specifically a python flask application.

You can use their eb CLI to get a snap shot ...

```
eb logs
```

But I would like to do (similar to what [heroku offers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval))...

```
eb logs --tail
```

Has any one accomplished this?

Thanks!

---

Some references:

- [Working with logs on Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.loggingS3.title.html)
- [EB CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/code/6752709412171743)

Comment: I know this is old but, would you like to mark one of the answers as correct? The one you ended up using perhaps? Thanks

Comment: check this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

2021 Update:

Now the best way to do this might be to use AWS CLI v2:

```
aws logs tail $log_group_name --follow
```

(Note: I couldn't get this working for me because of permissions errors.)

My previous answer was:

This is now as simple as:

```
eb logs --stream
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-logs.html

(I realize [posit lab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943205/167369) already included the `--stream` option but I keep skimming by that answer because I want to see all the logs, not just one group. And if my memory were better I wouldn't have to keep Googling the same question and ending up at the same place.)

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR: InvalidOptionsError - Can't retrieve instance logs for environment huru-api2-dev. Instance log streaming is disabled.`

Comment: I guess this has some answers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

Comment: Likely need to run `eb logs --cloudwatch-logs enable` first

Comment: @JarvisJohnson I ran this and got `The following instances have not responded in the allowed command timeout time. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) '<instance-id>'. Aborting the operation.` Somehow Beanstalk is extremely slow for any operation I tried. Anything leads to timeout.

Comment: @LoganYang that sounds like a deeper issue - like beanstalk can't even got a response from the instances.  I would try to rebuild the environment...

Comment: @JarvisJohnson I was able to run `eb local`, run the docker container and spin up the server locally with no problem, everything works on my machine. Haven't been able to figure out what's wrong after that. Every time I try to get the log, it starts updating the environment and gets stuck for several minutes, then it says log retrieved but it's nowhere to be found...

Comment: Hi! I get output from calling `eb logs --stream` but it's not updating automatically when new log entries are coming in. I have to run the command again to see the new entries.. Any clue what might be wrong?

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work anymore. (Or maybe it never did?!)
I guess you need to [pass the log group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943205/167369) in with `-g` or use the [CloudWatch Logs UI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48659489/167369).

Comment: I'm suffering the same issue with `jonahe`. On cloudwatch console, logs are refreshed but not in my terminal though I appended `-g` to specify the log gorup and `--stream`.

Comment: @umi0410 I don't think that method works anymore. I updated my answer to use aws cli version 2.

Answer (score 26):

**UPDATE:** My answer keeps getting upvotes, but things have changed since 2013. It is now easier to tail EB logs—look at [posit labs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46943205/167369) for a simpler way to do it :-).

---

**Original answer:**

I had been struggling with this one too. The eb CLI utility does not seem to allow for tailing your application logs currently.

However, you can tail these logs by:

1. Creating a key pair in the EC2 console (which should give you a `.pem` file)
2. Linking your EB instance to this key pair (in the EB console)
3. Finding the public DNS of your instance in the EC2 console
4. Connecting to your instance via ssh (`ssh -i [yourpemfile.pem] ec2-user@[your.public.dns]
5. Tailing your log file. For a Node.js application, that's `tail -f /var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log`. I don't know what's the equivalent for a Flask application.

(Thanks to [Richard Soutar](https://coderwall.com/p/sau6mg) for pointing me in the right direction on this one.)

Comment: tail -f /var/app/current/log/production.log for a Rails app deployed using AWS Beanstalk

Comment: `eb ssh` allows to skip 1-4 steps and go straight to one of your running instances

Comment: for rails with puma the following works for me: 

**eb ssh** and then **tail -f /var/log/puma/puma.log**

Comment: @AlekseyKulikov suggest you make that into an answer. I very nearly didn't read your comment.

Answer (score 19):

You can use the `-g` flag to set the log group, then use `--stream` to stream the results. No need to ssh into a specific machine.

```
eb logs -g /aws/elasticbeanstalk/yourApp-env/var/log/nodejs/nodejs.log --stream
```

Comment: hmmm how we get that path? I am using docker, so would it be `eb logs -g /aws/elasticbeanstalk/yourApp-env/var/log/docker/docker.log --stream` ? I hate guessing bro lol

Comment: I get this error: `ERROR: InvalidOptionsError - Can't retrieve instance logs for environment huru-api2-dev. Instance log streaming is disabled.`

Comment: I guess this has some answers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

Comment: This works but not for upcoming logs. it last logs for only once. new coming logs not showing

Answer (score 8):

You might not need eb logs for it, try `eb ssh` first then

```
tail -f /var/log/*
```

Answer (score 2):

So for others who are still looking for it, I wrote a small tool to tail logs for elastic beanstalk environment, you just need to specify environment name and file name, it will do the SSH and tail the file of each instance.

```
./eb-tail env-name
```

or

```
./eb-tail env-name -f '/path/to/file'
```

https://github.com/ahmednasir91/eb-tail

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

Grab the location of the logfile you want from `eb logs`

```
eb logs
```

Each log EB displays comes with a `-------` preceding/prefacing it. For instance, for Passenger logs on Rails:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/app/support/logs/production.log
-------------------------------------
```

Then SSH into the server and tail the logs:

```
eb ssh    # may have to eb ssh --setup for first time use

# from inside the server
tail -f /var/app/support/logs/production.log
```

Answer (score 2):

More Detailed Answer as I was getting errors using `eb logs --stream` and with `tail` in SSH:

1. Enable Cloudwatch in eb CLI using this command `eb logs --cloudwatch-logs enable`.
2. Go to AWS Console and Open Cloudwatch. Now, go to Logs Groups, select the log you want to stream, web.stdout.log in my case and
   copy its path as highlighted in below image

   [image]
3. Now, open the eb CLI again and type `eb logs -g your_copied_path --stream`.  For example: `eb logs -g /aws/elasticbeanstalk/yourEbsApp-env/var/log/web.stdout.log --stream`. And then the log tailing will start.
4. (Optional) You can totally skip 3rd point and can directly stream the logs in above CloudWatch panel, just open the log group and
   select the log stream provided below it.

Answer (score 1):

For me it involved two steps.

You need to run `eb logs --stream`, but before this, run:
`eb logs --cloudwatch-logs enable`

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tail the logs directly as AWS EB aggregates several logs together.assuming it's the application log that interests you, you can go to the EC2 tab and press the connect button on the actual server (you may need to define key-pair, just follow the instructions). Once logged into the server you can tail your log from there.

Answer (score 0):

Something I use to tail several logs from multiple servers, including aws, is the following:

```
for $server in server-1 server-2 server-3 server-4; do
    ssh -t $server -f "tail -f /var/log/some-process/error.log|sed -e 's/^/$server /'" &
done
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/iolloyd/da60ef316643d7894bdf

It allows me to monitor multiple remote instances in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use the eb-cli, but the simplest way to stream logs would be to use `eb logs -cw enable` then reading the stream in the cloudwatch portal.

Answer (score -6):

I don't have an environment where i can test this but from looking at the code it looks like you can do:

eb logs tail

check out constants.py line 129

Comment: I have moved on from EB for a couple of reasons.  Let me know if anyone can confirm this.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like the `eb logs tail` makes any difference over `eb logs`

Comment: `ERROR: No Environment found for EnvironmentName = 'tail'.`

Comment: This answer is wrong. There is no such thing in eb cli.