# Elastic Bean Stalk Real Time Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently I am working on Heroku, and I want to migrate my Node.js server to Elastic Bean Stalk. But the issue is that after migration, I see that there is no console that provides real-time logs for the whole machine. But Heroku offers this; can anyone tell me how to do the same on AWS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CLI to tail logs from AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17051925/is-there-a-cli-to-tail-logs-from-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: No this is a bad idea because when we are working on production there are so many logs and filtering out from CLI will not work we can not filter out logs by their category. I need something which gives logs very easily and clearly of what is going on in my server.